# In vue js with the help of loop i am showing all elements and i want to hide one element from that but all elements are getting hide

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, loops, if-statement

[First Image without clicking on Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAEqQ.png)

[Second Image when i click on Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmt6i.png)

here when i click on which ever edit button all the task which is in loop plus it is in if part will be hidden and else part will be shown but i want to hide particular task when i click on edit button. can anyone help me with that?.

```js
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            newTaskTitle: "",
            isEditing : false
        }
    },
    props:{
        Task:{
            type:Array,
            required: true
        },
    },
    methods:{
        removeTask: function(idx){
            this.Index = idx;
            this.$emit('remove',this.Index);
        },
        EditTaskI(tsk){
            this.task = tsk;
            console.log(this.task);
            this.isEditing = this.isEditing == true ? false : true;
            this.newTaskTitle = this.task;
        },
        TaskUpdated(indx){
            this.Index = indx
            this.$emit('update',this.Index,this.newTaskTitle);
            this.isEditing = this.isEditing == true ? false : true;
        },
        taskContentChange(e){
            this.newTaskTitle = e.target.value;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <section v-if="Task.length > 0" class="taskMainSection">
        <section v-for="(tasks,index) in Task" :key="index" class="sectionTask" >
            <section class="TaskBox" v-if="!isEditing">
                <div class="TaskTitleList" >
                    <div class="TaskSection">
                            <p class="listTask">{{ tasks.Task }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="OptionSectionMain">
                    <div class="OptionSection">
                            <p class="removeTask fa fa-close" @click="removeTask(index)"></p>
                            <p class="editTask fa fa-edit" @click="EditTaskI(tasks.Task,index)"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="TaskBoxEdit" v-else>
                <div class="TaskTitleList" >
                    <div class="TaskSection">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="newTaskTitle" @change="taskContentChange">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="OptionSectionMain">
                    <div class="OptionSection">
                            <p class="removeTask fa fa-check" @click="TaskUpdated(index)"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of boolean use index for `isEditing`:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <section v-if="Task.length > 0" class="taskMainSection">
    <section v-for="(tasks,index) in Task" :key="index" class="sectionTask" >
      <section class="TaskBox" >
        <div class="TaskTitleList" >
          <div class="TaskSection">
            <p class="listTask">{{ tasks.Task }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="OptionSectionMain">
          <div class="OptionSection">
            <p class="removeTask fa fa-close" @click="removeTask(index)"></p>
            <p class="editTask fa fa-edit" @click="EditTaskI(tasks.Task,index)"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="TaskBoxEdit" v-if="isEditing === index">
        <div class="TaskTitleList" >
          <div class="TaskSection">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="newTaskTitle" @change="taskContentChange">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="OptionSectionMain">
          <div class="OptionSection">
            <p class="removeTask fa fa-check" @click="TaskUpdated(index)"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
  `,
  data(){
    return{
      newTaskTitle: "",
      isEditing : null
    }
  },
  props:{
    Task:{
      type:Array,
      required: true 
    },
  },
  methods:{
    removeTask(idx){
    console.log(idx)
      this.$emit('remove', idx);
    },
    EditTaskI(tsk, i){
      this.task = tsk;
      this.isEditing = i;
      this.newTaskTitle = this.task;
    },
    TaskUpdated(indx){
      this.Index = indx
      this.$emit('update',this.Index,this.newTaskTitle);
      this.isEditing = null;
    },
    taskContentChange(e){
      this.newTaskTitle = e.target.value;
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data(){
    return{
      tasks: [{Task: 'aaa'}, {Task: 'bbb'}, {Task: 'ccc'}],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTasks(i, name) {
      this.tasks[i].Task = name
    },
    removeTask(i) {
      this.tasks.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child :task="tasks" @update="updateTasks" @remove="removeTask"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your help i took reference from your solution and did it in my way and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** `isEditing` is a culprit in your code. As `isEditing` is a global variable containing `boolean` value. Hence, On edit you are updating the value of isEditing which impact for all the tasks.

**Solution :** Instead of defining isEditing globally, You can add isEditing in each object of Task array. So that you can just update the value of clicked task not for every task.

Your template code will be **:**

```
<section class="TaskBox" v-if="!tasks.isEditing">
```

instead of

```
<section class="TaskBox" v-if="!isEditing">
```